# Why is my react native app returning unexpected token?

Tags: react-native

My source code is:

```
import React from 'react';

import Home from "./components/Home";
import Chat from "./components/Chat";

import {
    Router,
    Scene
} from "react-native-router-flux";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return {
            <Router>
                <Scene key="root">
                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home" />
                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Chat" />
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        };
    }
}

export default App
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: /Users/owner/code/ChatApp/src/App.js: Unexpected token (14:12)
```

What is the error in my code?

Comment: On the render method, when you do the return your are opening { } instead of parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return function should be :
`return ( ... );`
instead of `return { ... };`